# Calculating A Cycle number using dates for a 28 day repeating cycle

Tags: php, datetime

I have a job that runs every 28 days. and I want to assign it a cycle number based on a starting reference date.

e.g

1st cycle is 01/27/22. and that cycle number would be 2201.
subsequently I want to calculate the cycle number based on the current date. but for each year there could be either 13 or 14 cycles.

I've managed to figure out the number of cycles since the reference date to figure out the latest cycle date (see below)

```
const REF_ZERO_DATE = '01/27/2022';
const REF_ZERO_CYCLE_YEAR = "22";
const REF_ZERO_CYCLE_NUM = "01"; 
    
    $today = new \DateTime("2023/12/29");
    echo ("Today = ".$today->format("Y/m/d")."\n");
    $ref_zero = new \DateTime(self::REF_ZERO_DATE);
    echo ("ref_zero = ".$ref_zero->format("Y/m/d")."\n");

    $number_of_days_since_ref_zero = $today->diff($ref_zero)->format("%a");
    echo ("Number of days since ref zero = ".$number_of_days_since_ref_zero."\n");

    $number_of_cycles_since_ref_zero = floor($number_of_days_since_ref_zero/28);
    echo ("Number of cycles since ref zero = ".$number_of_cycles_since_ref_zero."\n");

    $interval = 'P' . $number_of_cycles_since_ref_zero*28 . 'D';
    echo ("Interval = ".$interval);

    $date_of_lastest_cycle = date_add($ref_zero,new \DateInterval($interval));
    echo ("last Cycle Date = ".$date_of_lastest_cycle->format("Y/m/d")."\n");
```

But my math for the cycle adjustment is missing coping with 12 or 13 cycle in a specific year.

Comment: Can you find the first cycle for a certain year? If you can find that one...

Comment: I would have to iterate from the reference date and look for a year change but that wouldn't be very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not explicitly stated whether the cycle of the previous year continues into the next or not.

The scenario in which the cycles can overlap between years is more complicated, so this is assumed.

The interval count code was extracted to the following function:

```php
function calculateIntervalCount($startDate, $endDate, $interval) {
    $start = new \DateTime($startDate);
    $end = new \DateTime($endDate);
    $interval = new \DateInterval($interval);
    
    $periodDays = intval($end->diff($start)->format('%a'));
    $intervalDays = intval($interval->format('%d'));
    
    return floor($periodDays / $intervalDays);
}
```

There are two cases when calculating the interval count of a particular year:

1. year of start and end are the same year
2. year of end is after year of start

In the first case the interval count is the same as the interval count of the whole period.

In the second case the interval count of a particular year can be calculated from the difference between the interval counts of the whole period and the period before the end year.

The following function returns the cycle number:

```
function calculateCycleNumber($startDate, $endDate, $interval) {
    $totalCycles = calculateIntervalCount($startDate,$endDate,$interval);
    
    $startYear = intval((new \DateTime($startDate))->format('Y'));
    $endYear = intval((new \DateTime($endDate))->format('Y'));
    
    if($startYear < $endYear) {
        $endOfLastYearDate = (new \DateTime($endDate))->modify('last day of December last year')->format('Y-m-d');
        $cyclesSinceEndOfLastYear = calculateIntervalCount($endOfLastYearDate, $endDate, $interval);
        $yearCycle = $totalCycles - $cyclesSinceEndOfLastYear + 1;
    } else {
        $yearCycle = $totalCycles;
    }
    
    $yearCode = substr($endYear,-2);
    $yearCycleCode = sprintf('%02d', $yearCycle);

    return $yearCode . $yearCycleCode;
}
```

A cycle number of 2314 was obtained with the inputs provided.

```php
echo calculateCycleNumber('01/27/2022','2023/12/29','P28D');
```

Note that 14 is possible in case of overlapping cycles.

Comment: +1  Yes you're correct there could be 14 cycles (that was true in 2020) although in this case there will be only 13 periods in 2023, I think we can lose the +1 . The cycles do continue into the next year so for example if you have a cycle date of 12/29/22 (2212) the next cycle would be 01/26/23 (this would be 2301).   This looks like a great solution I'm going to understand it, test it and will mark as answered when I can.

Comment: The part I was missing was the use of the DateTime -> modify had no clue that existed as a feature and how to exploit it. Thanks

Comment: last comment for this case if the date was 01-12-23 your would want to report 22-13 as the current cycle number

Comment: I had to add some code to cope with year ends and multiple years to finish off but the key was the modify method..

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp, where you add 28 days each time so you get the next date and so on.

Get the next timestamp

```
$next_date = strtotime('+28 day', $timestamp);
```

Convert to readable date

```
echo date('m/d/Y', $next_date);
```

Comment: Yes, I have that under control.  What I'm trying to derive is the cycle number ie. "2211" would be the 11th 28 day cycle in 2022.

Comment: I am bit confused about your requirement

Comment: See answer below, but thanks for your contribution